# How to let compiler interpret as boolean context

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote following function:

```
def has_voted(request, question):
    cookie = request.COOKIES.get(COOKIE_NAME)
    ip = get_client_ip(request)
    return ((cookie and re.match(COOKIE_PATTERN, cookie) and
            question.id in map(int, cookie.split('-'))) or
            (ip and is_valid_ip_address(ip) and
            question.voter_set.filter(ip=ip).exists()))
```

The function always returns None, but I want the compiler to interpret it in a boolean context like it does with if-statements:

```
if cookie:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return a boolean, return a boolean:

```
return bool((cookie and re.match(COOKIE_PATTERN, cookie) and
            question.id in map(int, cookie.split('-'))) or
            (ip and is_valid_ip_address(ip) and
            question.voter_set.filter(ip=ip).exists()))
```